# Prove $S$ is composite

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**HINTS ONLY**

> Let $a, b, c, d, e, f$ be positive integers. Suppose that $S = a + b + c + d + e + f$
>   divides both $abc + def $ and $ab + bc + ca − de − ef − fd$. Prove that $S$ is composite.

**Must be solved using polynomials in some way**

**HINTS ONLY**

I was thinking of defining $P(x) = (x + a)(x + b)(x+c) + (x + d)(x + e)(x + f)$ such that $P(0) = abc + def$. And $S | P(0)$.

But besides that, I dont see anything obvious.

Hints please?

Comment: This looks familiar; do you know the (original) source of the problem?

Comment: @bakula IMO shortlist 2005, problem N3, see [here](http://www.imomath.com/imocomp/sl05_0707.pdf).

Comment: @Wojowu thanks :)

Comment: Why is the hint unclear? Another hint (to add to the answer): [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $S$ divides all coefficients of $f(x)=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)-(x-d)(x-e)(x-f)$, so it divides $f(d)$. What would happen if $S$ was prime?

Comment: (+1), mmm. $S | f(d) = (a + d)(d + b)(d + c)$. If $S$ is prime then it is not divisible by any other numbers. $f(d) = kS + 0 = kS$ for some integer $k$. Then $S = f(d)/k$. No other number divides $S$, so $\pmod{f(d)}$ it gives: $S \equiv t \pmod{f(d)} \implies S \equiv t \pmod{kS} \implies S = t + nkS.$ For an integer $n$. And $t > 0$. Is this headed the right direction?

Comment: This isn't exactly how I would go about doing it. I would go and use the further hint which user236182 has given in a comment to the question.

Comment: Okay. So $f(d) = (d +a)(d+b)(d+c)$, and so $S$ must divide at least a pair or another factor. So, suppose $S| (d + a)$ at least. Then what could I do? I don't see a possible end to this, if I go about this way. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Remember that $S=a+b+c+d+e+f>d+a$.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this, and thought this was a contradiction. But then realized that this isn't the only case. Consider: $S| (a + d)(d  + b)$ then, $S|(ad + ab  + d^2 + db)$ which doesn't lead anywhere

Comment: If $S\mid(d+a)(d+b)(d+c)$, then $S$ divides one of $d+a,d+b,d+c$. All of them are between $0$ and $S$.

Comment: Just one question, how does $S$ divide the coefficients of the polynomial?

Comment: Just expand the brackets.